# Startupuri in a wpf application not found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I need help about this problem [image: error]

I need to put the startup view The `Home.xaml` but when i run the application an error indicates that the view `Home` is not found appears.

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. StartupUri is a relative URI from App.xaml. Also, its not a namespace/class path, its a folder path.
2. StartupUri="View/Home.xaml" should do it.

Comment: Just a clarification here, it doesn't actually have to be relative to App.xaml, you can also use pack syntax to reference files in child libraries e.g. `StartupUri="pack://application:,,,assembly_name;component/path_to_page"`.